# Kafka consumer does not start processing from offset#0

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a topic with single partition. I have 2 different consumer groups. Each consumer group has a consumer. Consumer group#1 has been running ever since; I started producer. On the other hand, Consumer group#2 was just started with auto.offset.reset=earliest parameter.

Though, consumer group#2 started consuming messages that were rewritten recently.

Q1: How can I force consumer in consumer group#2 to start from the beginning ?

Q2: Why auto.offset.reset (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/- What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server ) is not working? As it is not working as I expected; this means that I have not understood it correctly.

Kafka 2.11-0.11.0.1
Confluent-python v0.11.5

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError
c = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'mybroker',
    'group.id': 'mygroup', # I update group.id everytime I run
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
})
c.subscribe(['mytopic'])
while True:
    msg = c.poll(1.0)
    if msg is None:
        continue
    if msg.error():
        print("Consumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue
    print('Received message: {}'.format(msg.value().decode('utf-8')))
c.close()
```

**Conclusion**: Confluent API for python seems to have issue. As auto.offset.reset works fine for Java clients.

Comment: is it typo `auto.offset.rest`? should be `auto.offset.reset`.

Comment: It is auto.offset.reset.